# Why isn't the naked keyword or inline assembler supported on x64 programs?

Tags: c++, windows, security

I was trying to allocate and write a detour function in an external 64 bit program when I came into an interesting problem. The function had prologue and epilogue code that accessed hard coded addresses. This was after the suspension of the main thread after startup since the program was single-threaded.

To fix this I tried using __declspec(naked) or at least an inline assembler but neither are supported on x64. I later decided to write an assembler file but I couldn't help but wonder why the lack of support on x64 for Visual Studio.

Comment: Visual Studio's [MASM for x64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/masm-for-x64-ml64-exe?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Inline assembly shouldn't be relied on. It's fragmented and could lead to undefined behaviors. Also if the compiler had to work around your code it might interfere with optimization and result in worse over all code. The better practice is to create a separate assembly file and link it to your project.

Comment: It's a design decision by Microsoft, I'm not sure what more one can say.

Comment: @NateEldredge I was just wondering if there were any internal reasons for it. Like something to do with how assembly works or the operating system. It just seemed odd they only gave support to ARM and x86 architectures.